# UWP Image not centered when source set from SVGImageSource

Tags: svg, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an image centered in my grid like this:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White">
    <Image Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="capturedPhoto" Height="{x:Bind Path=CrosshairHeight, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="{x:Bind Path=CrosshairWidth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And I set the source in the .cs file like this:

```
    ImageProperties imageProperties = await crosshairFile.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await crosshairFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        if (crosshairFile.ContentType == "image/svg+xml")
        {
            SvgImageSource svgImage = new SvgImageSource();
            svgImage.RasterizePixelHeight = imageProperties.Height;
            svgImage.RasterizePixelWidth = imageProperties.Width;
            await svgImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            capturedPhoto.Source = svgImage;
        }
        else
        {
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 100;

            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            capturedPhoto.Source = bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

For PNG images using the BitmapImage, it seems to be centered fine. For XMLs however, it will not be centered, but rather rendering like this (set stack panel background to white to show)
:
[image]

The SVG file contents are this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="300" height="300" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;"><defs></defs><g id="two-0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" opacity="1"><path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 150 80)" id="two-106" d="M -5 -25 L 5 -25 L 5 25 L -5 25 Z " fill="#00FF4C" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path><path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 150 220)" id="two-107" d="M -5 -25 L 5 -25 L 5 25 L -5 25 Z " fill="#00FF4C" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path><path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 80 150)" id="two-108" d="M -25 -5 L 25 -5 L 25 5 L -25 5 Z " fill="#00FF4C" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path><path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 220 150)" id="two-109" d="M -25 -5 L 25 -5 L 25 5 L -25 5 Z " fill="#00FF4C" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path><path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 150 150)" id="two-110" d="M 10 0 C 10 2.111792 9.33145 4.169376 8.090169 5.877852 C 6.848889 7.586328 5.098603 8.857985 3.090169 9.510565 C 1.081735 10.163144 -1.081736 10.163144 -3.09017 9.510565 C -5.098604 8.857985 -6.84889 7.586328 -8.09017 5.877852 C -9.331451 4.169376 -10 2.111792 -10 0 C -10 -2.111793 -9.331451 -4.169377 -8.09017 -5.877853 C -6.84889 -7.586329 -5.098604 -8.857986 -3.09017 -9.510566 C -1.081736 -10.163145 1.081735 -10.163145 3.090169 -9.510566 C 5.098603 -8.857986 6.848889 -7.586329 8.090169 -5.877853 C 9.33145 -4.169377 10 -2.111793 10 0 Z " fill="#00FF4C" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path></g></svg>
```

Comment: What are the values of CrosshairHeight, CrosshairWidth, imageProperties.Height, imageProperties.Width?

Comment: @emoacht CrosshairHeight and CrosshairWidth are 100 and imageProperties height and width should be 300

Comment: I found that if those values are set directly, the image is centered. It suggests that you made a mistake elsewhere you have not shown.

Comment: Image properties are gotten from the file itself, they aren't set directly  ImageProperties imageProperties = await crosshairFile.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the downvotes on what is a legitimate question. Turns out that changing the SVG from

```
width="300" height="300"
```

to

```
viewBox="0 0 300 300"
```

makes the image centering work. Definitely a bug with `SVGImageSource`

[image]